# jquery ui creates a lot of undesirable spans

Tags: php, css, jquery-ui, html

I've a form using jquery ui , 
I must do a radio choice wich takes the values from DB so i tried this :

```
    //function wich reutrn applicable ratio for the pricing
function getAvailableCoeff(){


echo "<td>Coeff : </td>";
    echo "<td><div class='radio'>";
    $req = "SELECT coef,id_type FROM type_client WHERE valide =1 GROUP BY coef";
    $res = mysql_query($req);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $id = 'coeff'.$row['id_type'];
        $value = $row['coef'];
        $input = "<label for='$id'>$value</label>";
        $input .= "<input type='radio'id='$id' name='coeff' value='$value'/>";
        echo $input;
    }
    echo "</div></td>";
}
```

Nothing very difficult no ? But when i sent it to integration server i saw enormous radio buttons ( they are 3 atm)!
[i let you check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7XgX.png)
(on the screen the "1","2","3","4","quadri","5","6" radios buttons are hardcoded with this syntax : `<input type="radio" id="spT_radio-coul-1" value="1" name="nbCoul" /> <label for="spT_radio-coul-1">1</label>`

Moreover the radio buttondon't pass in the form sumbission , `$_POST['coef']` is still empty..
So i take a look to the html and .. WTF ?
Each radio button get this kind of code :

```
    <label for="coeff5" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">
<span class="ui-button-text">
<span class="ui-button-text">
<span class="ui-button-text">
<span class="ui-button-text">
<span class="ui-button-text">0.66</span></span></span></span></span></span></label>
```

So jquery auto generates all theses spans but how to remove them in order to get normals radio buttons ?
Have anyone encountered thsi kind of problems with jquery ui ?

TEMPORARY (ugly) SOLUTION :

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
padding:2px;
!important;
```

}

FINAL SOLUTION (Thx SuperScript) :

```
 //function wich reutrn applicable ratio for the pricing
function getAvailableCoeff($form){
    echo "<td>Coeff : </td>";
    echo "<td><div class='radio'>";
    $req = "SELECT coef,id_type FROM type_client WHERE valide =1 GROUP BY coef";
    $res = mysql_query($req);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $id = $form.'coeff'.$row['id_type'].$i;
        $value = $row['coef'];
        $input = "<label for='$id'>$value</label>";
        $input .= "<input type='radio' id='$id' name='coeff' value='$value'/>";
        echo $input;
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</div></td>";
}
```

I pass a string value for each call , like that the id's are really unique !

Comment: A link to a real page showing the problem would be really useful.

Comment: In that link, I don't see any `coeff` inputs?  Where are they?

Comment: my bad , by disabling login requirement i unvoluntary disable db access to.. 
It's good now

Comment: This could have something to do with you including `function.js` twice?

Comment: i remove one of the two , doesn't change anything, but thx for repporting this mistake :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49086/discussion-between-superscript-and-azrael-404)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.  I had just figured it out when my internet connection died.  So, I waited for a couple hours, then posted this.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem is using duplicate `id`s.

On the page, all of your `<input>` use the same sets of `id`s (`#coeff5`,`#coeff2`,`#coeff1`).  jQuery UI uses those `id`s to add the spans, so the duplicates are wrecking it.

`id`s must be unique.

I made some test cases for this:

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/PGcL4

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGcL4/1).

So, you would change your PHP code to:

```
//function wich reutrn applicable ratio for the pricing
function getAvailableCoeff(){
    echo "<td>Coeff : </td>";
    echo "<td><div class='radio'>";
    $req = "SELECT coef,id_type FROM type_client WHERE valide =1 GROUP BY coef";
    $res = mysql_query($req);

    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $id = 'coeff'.$row['id_type'].$i;
        $value = $row['coef'];
        $input = "<label for='$id'>$value</label>";
        $input .= "<input type='radio' id='$id' name='coeff' value='$value'/>";
        echo $input;
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</div></td>";
}
```

That makes all of the `id`s unique like required.